# Right before your very eyes

Tags: riddle, word

I am all of the principal, the primary, the parent-
I am untainted, but made through contamination.

I am peace, I am death;
I am good, and I am safe.
I am new, I am brilliant;
I am clean, and I am perfect.

My kind have caused strife when compared to others,
The hues of a bee, we no longer stick together.
In this way I may not be peace, I may not be good.
We may be the ones storming down the neighborhood.

Up in the sky, down on the ground,
Right before your very eyes-
Right here, right now, can I be found.
Multiple meanings have I, multiple lives I live,
But I ask you this one question:
Who am I?

Hint 1:

> "primary": noun 2

Comment: Rot7(Gbvx ubh, ur max ptr :W). Now write the translation in Rot19 :)

Comment: Yes, it is for another of my riddles that is unsolved. :) @user477343

Comment: I enjoy that everyone seems to overlook "I am *all* of ... ". The rest of the riddle makes it pretty easy to overlook "all", but it's quite important!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> Colors?

I am all of the principal, the primary, the parent-

> Everything has a color and there such things as primary colors and the hint suggests this.

I am untainted, but made through contamination.

> Mixing colors.

I am peace, I am death;

> Peace may be blue but death is black.

I am good, and I am safe.

> Other colors.

I am new, I am brilliant;

> Green can mean new but brilliant may mean purple.

I am clean, and I am perfect.

> Other colors, maybe white for clean.

My kind have caused strife when compared to others,

> Race.

The hues of a bee, we no longer stick together.

> Yellow and black?

In this way I may not be peace, I may not be good.
We may be the ones storming down the neighborhood.

> Still race.

Up in the sky, down on the ground,

> Blue sky, brown dirt.

Right before your very eyes-

> We recieve color in our eye cones.

Right here, right now, can I be found.

> Black and white on my screen.

Multiple meanings have I, multiple lives I live,

> There are many different colors.

---

OP's Edit:

> The specific color is "white"

I am all of the principal, the primary, the parent-
I am untainted, but made through contamination.

> White is made up of all colors mixing together, with black being no colors together.

I am peace, I am death;

> White is a symbol of peace for many countries, and in China white is the symbol for death. The rest are additional symbolisms related to "white".

My kind have caused strife when compared to others,
The hues of a bee, we no longer stick together.
In this way I may not be peace, I may not be good.
We may be the ones storming down the neighborhood.

> As found: race. "White", "Asian", and "Black" are some of the largest racial groups today, and there is a large amount of tension despite the progress.

Up in the sky, down on the ground,

> Clouds in the sky, many human-made buildings or other items on the ground, white flowers and other flora, etc.

Right before your very eyes-
Right here, right now, can I be found.

> There's white on the screen right now!

Comment: This is the most convincing answer to me. Some of the lines also seem to be alluding to the fact that we're looking at a screen made of RGB colours.

Comment: Yes! This is very close. The riddle alludes to one shade in particular- can you figure out which one? You are correct with "my kind..." as well.

Answer (score 3):

My guess...

> You are an Atom

I am all of the principal, the primary, the parent-

> You're like an Atom, everything cause everything consists of you

I am untainted, but made through contamination.

> Hmmm made through contamination? Like radioactive contamination. Would suit to an Atom

I am peace, I am death;
I am good, and I am safe.
I am new, I am brilliant;
I am clean, and I am perfect

> Again, you're everything

My kind have caused strife when compared to others,
The hues of a bee, we no longer stick together.
In this way I may not be peace, I may not be good.
We may be the ones storming down the neighborhood.

> You've got a bad reputation because Atomic bombs cause serious threats to humanity. "we no longer stick together" - when nuclear fission occurs, you really are splittibg apart and do so with an enormous speed "storming down the neighboorhood"

Up in the sky, down on the ground,
Right before your very eyes-
Right here, right now, can I be found.

> Again, you're everything cause matter is the only thing our world really consists of (& photons)

Multiple meanings have I, multiple lives I live,
But I ask you this one question:
Who am I?

> Multiple meanings: Superhero Atom, ATOM War Tank, Intel Atom and so on. Multiple Lives: you are only as long a part of a living thing until it dies, then you get consumed for instance and are living another life. In other words: in me might be an Atom, which was part of a brain cell of a Brachiosaurus.

Comment: Both of these answers are thinking on quite the small scale! While we could think of it at such a size, the term I seek is much bigger and broader. Added a hint.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Bacteria or Germs?

I am all of the principal, the primary, the parent-

> Bacteria is the earliest form of life.

I am untainted, but made through contamination.

> Bacteria is just bacteria, but bacteria are spread by touching things, coughing, etc.

I am peace, I am death
I am good, and I am safe.
I am new, I am brilliant;
I am clean, and I am perfect.

> There are good and bad bacteria. For example, there are bacteria that cleans your stomach, but there are also bacteria that will kill you.

My kind have caused strife when compared to others,

> The plague

The hues of a bee, we no longer stick together.

> I'm not too sure on this one.

In this way I may not be peace, I may not be good.

> Again, deadly bacteria. Bacteria multiply

We may be the ones storming down the neighborhood.

> This could be referring to an outbreak of something.

Up in the sky, down on the ground,
Right before your very eyes-
Right here, right now, can I be found.

> Bacteria is everywhere

Multiple meanings have I, multiple lives I live,

> Bacteria or germs have multiple meanings. Like wheat germ for example. Most of the same type of bacteria are genetically identical, hence they live multiple lives.

Comment: Both of these answers are thinking on quite the small scale! While we could think of it at such a size, the term I seek is much bigger and broader. Added a hint.